# How to map flood areas from a set of points containing surface and height of water?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, elevation, flood

I am working on the damages made by the typhoon Haiyan. I use QGIS 2.0 with extensions and toolbox, and MapInfo. I have vectors, rasters of the place.

I want to map the flood area along the coastline with analyze of the height of water. The picture below shows a result approaching what i would like to obtain

[image: area of inundation and height of water]

Beside i have a set of 70 points, with long/lat, area inundation, height of water

[image: table of data]

that are represented on this map

[image: map of data]

I suppose that a Satellite image has been used to get the points.

My questions are:

1. is it possible to represent the areas of inundation with the attributes in the table?
2. If no, what is the method they could have used ? (may be not easy to guess it!)
3. If yes, what is the method to proceed?

Anyone has an idea ?
Thanks a lot for your help:)

Comment: Is "MaxHei" the height of water above solid ground or height of water above mean sea level? Do you have an elevation model of the area?

Comment: above sea level and yes i have a DEM of the area

Answer (score 2):

I've never done flood modeling before but one simple approach I could think of is

1. Interpolate the point data height of water values to generate a height of water raster
2. Subtract the elevation model height from the water height raster to determine which areas would be under water

Comment: and the point 2 is done using raster calculator, right?

Comment: @LaurentM right!